# Checking if two floating point numbers are equal

Tags: c++, floating-point

Is this the best way to check if two floating point numbers are equal, or close to being equal?

```
template <class T>
bool IsEqual(T rhs, T lhs)
{
    T diff = std::abs(lhs - rhs);

    T epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon( ) * std::max(std::abs(rhs), std::abs(lhs));

    return diff <= epsilon ;
}
```

Comment: So I should consider: 100000000000000000 and 100000000000000020 to be the same number?

Comment: PS. Typo inside std::max() you have two rhs.

Comment: @LokiAstari With floating point numbers, they are not accurate and the farther away you get from 1 the less accurate you get. Therefore, I'm trying to check if they are equal with some reason. To answer your question, yes those two values should be equal. But at the same time, I don't want 1 == 20

Comment: Correct. And if that is what you need fine. But it is not what most people are going to need. I would use @William Morris solution as this would be more normal usage as i do want to distinguish larger numbers.

Comment: @LokiAstari The thing is that you can't guarantee that your large numbers are stored accurately.

Comment: As i said last time; you are correct. Does not change anything in my previous statement.

Comment: When in doubt, consult [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/floating_point_comparison.html) for a comprehensive intro to different float comparisons.

Comment: You can avoid a *third parameter* if you can calculate the [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (unit in the last place) of a floating point number. Its not *that* difficult to calculate. Just use the larger of the two ulp's as an acceptable difference. But you will also need that epsilon you're currently using, to handle the *corner cases* like `0`, `INFINITY`, `NaN` (to be dealt with separately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really.  You want a third parameter that gives an acceptable difference -- this can be number of decimals, percent of value, or a fixed value, but it needs to be coming from outside to really be useful.

A function that does it with a constant diff, might be useful in some limited circumstances, but not generally.

Answer (score 4):

Seems unlikely.  `epsilon` from `std::numeric_limits` is the smallest increment representable by the type (around the value 1).

You want to check for something "close to" equal, but you don't say what close to means for you. Assuming it to be a few multiples of epsilon, the following check would seem reasonable:

```
const int FEW = 10;
T diff = std::abs(lhs - rhs);
T epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();

return diff < (epsilon * FEW);
```

Comment: From my understanding, floating point numbers get less and less accurate the further away you get from 1. While you code is fine, it is only gone work for a small lower range of floating point numbers.